# C# change table row class by time

Tags: c#

i am adding the list to the table  like so

```
    public ActionResult Add( string task , DateTime duedo , DateTime time)
{
    Task.Add(new Tasks { descripiton = task, duedo = duedo, time = DateTime.Now });
    Task.Sort((x, y) => DateTime.Compare(x.duedo, y.duedo));
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

and i am showing the form  in html

```
    <tbody>
    @foreach (var task in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @task.time
            </td>
            <td>
                @task.descripiton
            </td>
            <td id="time">
                @task.duedo
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

Question is how could i make a function that is able to change the table row color when Duedo date is about to come  or is over the current time . 
For example if the duedo time / date is 1 hour away the table row will turn red .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a class attribute to your row and fill it according to your conditions:

```
<tr class="@(task.duedo >= DateTime.Now.AddHours(-1) ? "due-in-one-hour" : task.duedo >= DateTime.Now ? "overdue" : "")">
```

Then, just define the classes in your stylesheet. To keep the code readable/manageable, I suggest putting the calculation of the class names in a helper function in your Razor file.

Comment: i added it but it still the same  .  i edited the css  . i am not sure if it still compears the datetime.

Comment: That solely depends on the logic of your application. Without more code, I'm afraid I cannot help you.

Comment: i edited it . first is worker.cshtml and the 
another is controller

Comment: At first sight, it looks ok to me. Could you check your rendered page (view page source) if the `<tr>` contain any class names for your tasks? If they do, you might have some other styles overriding the background color (maybe on `<td>` level).

Comment: it just says <tr class>

Comment: i also just changed to class name to  overdue and it changed the color then but if u do it by ur function it just says <tr class>

Comment: And you are sure, some of your tasks should be overdue, or at least due in the next hour? Because the output suggests the tasks' `duedo` is less than in one hour.

Comment: yes sorry about it thanx for the help :D i got it working :D